# How httpoxy works

Tags: httpoxy

I have been doing a task on detecting if httpoxy exists on a web server. I did not have any idea about it initially. After reading from a couple of sites, I understood how it works but I'm still unclear at certain places.

My understanding: The HTTP headers value are made available to CGI programs through environment variables.

Example: If we specify PATH in the header, it gets converted to HTTP_PATH.

Doubt: If we specify a non-existing header like Proxy, Will that get converted to HTTP_PROXY which collides with the already existing HTTP_PROXY environment variable that is set for proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In some environments, any header `Foo-Bar` will be passed as an environment variable `HTTP_FOO_BAR`.

This means any environment variable starting with `HTTP_` can't be trusted, because it can possibly be set by the user. In particular, `HTTP_PROXY` which often specify the outgoing proxy is a likely target.